# PostgreSQL - regex issue

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm trying the following instruction and I don't understand the TRUE value returned :

```
SELECT '1' ~ '(0[1-9])|[10-15]' ;

?column?
boolean
----------
t
```

If I make it simplier again, I still don't understand the value returned :

```
SELECT '1' ~ '[10-15]' ;

?column?
boolean
----------
t
```

Thank you for helping !

Thomas

Comment: i think you could use `SELECT '1' ~ '(0[1-9])|(1[0-5])';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex:

```
[10-15]
```

doesn't mean what you think it means. The things inside a character class (i.e. `[...]`) are individual characters, not strings. So that regex matches a `'1'`, anything between `'0'` and `'1'`, or a `'5'`; simplifying, we have `[015]`. In particular, that regex does not match anything between `'10'` and `'15'` as you seem to think.

I think you're looking for:

```
(0[1-9])|(1[0-5])
```

You just need to factor out the `'1'` in the second part of the alternation in the same way that you factored out the `'0'` in the first part.

Comment: That's it, thank you so much ! I didn't understand that... It is perfectly clear now. Have a good day.